# How the input data of smart contract function is packed in hex string before sending to ethereum network

Tags: ethereum

I want to understand this to parse data from the private chain transaction and get the input data that was sent for a particular transaction, I have tried many decoders but at some point, they fail.
This is the simple smart contract I tried using remix

```
   contract simple{

     uint256 deliveryID;
     string status;
     function stringAndUint(string _status,uint256 _deliveryID){
               status=_status;
               deliveryID=_deliveryID;
     }

    }
```

Input data generated:- 0x3c38b7fd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000067374617475730000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I can interpret the following from the above.

- function signature:0x3c38b7fd
- _status value:737461747573,
- _deliveryID:0c but i dont know why 4 is coming and extra 6 before 737461747573 .
- The input to function "stringAndUint " is: "status",12 
  Can some one help me understand how the input data is generated and packet in a long hex string

Answer (score 5):

Try taking a look here http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/abi-spec.html#argument-encoding and here http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types

Splitting up the encoding into 32 byte chunks gives:

- 3c38b7fd (function signature)
- 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040 (the location of the data part of the first parameter, measured in bytes from the start of the arguments block)
- 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c (12)
- 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006 (length of "status". the earlier 0..040 points here)
- 7374617475730000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ("status" then zeros padded out to the next multiple of 32 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

### What is the encoding used?

Solidity uses a ["Contract ABI" spec](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/abi-spec.html) for encoding.

### What's the deal with the extra (hex) 40 and 6?

*@Brendan's answer about these values is better than mine, so I'll delete this section. I'll leave the answer posted because the below section is still useful.*

### Reproducing programatically

There is an ABI-decoding tool in python, called [`eth-abi`](https://github.com/ethereum/eth-abi/), which you can use like so:

```
from eth_utils import to_bytes

encoded = to_bytes(hexstr="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000067374617475730000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")

from eth_abi import decode_abi

decoded = decode_abi(['string', 'uint256'], encoded)

assert decoded == (b'status', 12)
```

Comment: BTW, `decoded` looks broken: I would expect it to be returned as `'status'` instead of `b'status'`. I'll go file a ticket on it.